# Is there a way to input multiple dictionary values into a function?

Tags: python, pandas, list, time-series

I was wondering if there was an efficient way to pass dictionary values through a function. I am trying to sort occurrences into time bins and then use pandas to group the values by their labels. For each list of series, I would like to apply the following function.

I was able to apply to function to a singular list of values, but now trying to find a way to scale up to accommodate more values but getting lost in the logic.

```
[DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-29 10:10:00', '2020-02-13 10:10:00',
           '2020-02-21 10:10:00', '2020-02-25 10:10:00',
           '2020-02-27 10:10:00', '2020-02-28 10:10:00',
           '2020-02-29 10:10:00', '2020-03-02 10:10:00',
           '2020-03-06 10:10:00', '2020-03-14 10:10:00',
           '2020-03-29 10:10:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)]
 [DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-29 10:10:00', '2020-02-13 10:10:00',
           '2020-02-21 10:10:00', '2020-02-25 10:10:00',
           '2020-02-27 10:10:00', '2020-02-28 10:10:00',
           '2020-02-29 10:10:00', '2020-03-02 10:10:00',
           '2020-03-06 10:10:00', '2020-03-14 10:10:00',
           '2020-03-29 10:10:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)]
 [DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-29 10:10:00', '2020-02-13 10:10:00',
           '2020-02-21 10:10:00', '2020-02-25 10:10:00',
           '2020-02-27 10:10:00', '2020-02-28 10:10:00',
           '2020-02-29 10:10:00', '2020-03-02 10:10:00',
           '2020-03-06 10:10:00', '2020-03-14 10:10:00',
           '2020-03-29 10:10:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)]
```

---

```
def time_mapping(bins):
  bins = patient_dict.values()

  labels = ['30_days_before','fifteen_days_before','seven_days_before','three_days_before',
                             'one_day_before','app_day','one_day_after','three_days_after',
                             'seven_days_after','fifteen_days_before',
                             '30_days_after','Out-Of-Bounds']

df['Time Bin'] = pd.cut(row.eventDTTM.date(), bins, labels=labels, right=False)
```

df['time_bin']= df.apply(time_mapping, axis=1)

---

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but looks a lot like an inefficient way of binning, try `pandas.cut`

Comment: @mozway Let me try that I think I was concerned that since the bins are always changing I would have to use these modifiable intervals. Essentially I have to take a date then generate out dates that are between [-30 days, -15 days, -7 days ... 30 days]